# Text styling line-height on mobile not working (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mobile

stack community,
I have a strange issue concerning how my text is displayed on mobile.

Changing the line-height in @media didn't help and I'm out of ideas on what to do.
The text is cut on the top line and adding padding or margin doesn't help. Inside the google development tools, the preview looks fine, once opened on my phone the text is cut.

What could be the reason? How can I fix it?

Screenshots:
[screenshots uploaded to imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sya2.jpg)

Link: http://monifit.co.uk/

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Composer generating your style file and the following code cause the issue:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 690px)
body .row .col.section-title h1, body h1 {

line-height: 24.7px;
}
```

if you can't change it from your visual composer setting you can overwrite it by the following:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 690px)  body h1 {
  line-height: 40px !IMPORTANT;
}
```

Comment: I tried this several times but somehow it isn't working. Any ideas on how I can find the line of code that causes this?

Comment: one sec let check it again

Comment: I removed all extra styling now and made the font smaller. At least it's not cut now...

Comment: visual composer is generating the css in inline and you need to go to that page visual composer editor and find option to change css line height

Comment: i noticed that but why adding important to that variable is not overriding it should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used a "Gradient Text Element" where you could select h1-h6 and I used h1. Tried to change the h1-Size in the theme customizer but it didn't change on mobile. But I'm good now with the mobile size, it's small but better than having it cut.

Comment: I thought the same with the important - it usually works, I don't know why it didn't this time. Guess we'll never know. Still thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to get rid of the line-height in your css h1 tag using @media query max-width: whatever px;